# convert complex json to c# class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have been trying to deserialize the following json data into classes for 2 days using the help from similar questions on this and other sites, and might possibly be going brain dead.

I have this json data (apologies for length) and am trying, as a start to get the 'value' number in the 'Values' array:-

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "columnGrouping": [
      "area",
      "metricType",
      "period",
      "valueType"
    ],
    "rowGrouping": []
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "area": {
        "identifier": "E31000040",
        "label": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "altLabel": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "metricType": {
        "identifier": "948",
        "label": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "altLabel": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "period": {
        "identifier": "fq_Q1_2013_14",
        "label": "2013/14 Q1",
        "altLabel": "2013/14 Q1",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "valueType": {
        "identifier": "raw",
        "label": "Raw value",
        "isSummary": false
      }
    },
    {
      "area": {
        "identifier": "E31000040",
        "label": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "altLabel": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "metricType": {
        "identifier": "948",
        "label": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "altLabel": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "period": {
        "identifier": "fq_Q2_2013_14",
        "label": "2013/14 Q2",
        "altLabel": "2013/14 Q2",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "valueType": {
        "identifier": "raw",
        "label": "Raw value",
        "isSummary": false
      }
    },
    {
      "area": {
        "identifier": "E31000040",
        "label": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "altLabel": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "metricType": {
        "identifier": "948",
        "label": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "altLabel": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "period": {
        "identifier": "fq_Q3_2013_14",
        "label": "2013/14 Q3",
        "altLabel": "2013/14 Q3",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "valueType": {
        "identifier": "raw",
        "label": "Raw value",
        "isSummary": false
      }
    },
    {
      "area": {
        "identifier": "E31000040",
        "label": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "altLabel": "Gtr Manchester Fire",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "metricType": {
        "identifier": "948",
        "label": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "altLabel": "Accidental dwelling fires",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "period": {
        "identifier": "fq_Q4_2013_14",
        "label": "2013/14 Q4",
        "altLabel": "2013/14 Q4",
        "isSummary": false
      },
      "valueType": {
        "identifier": "raw",
        "label": "Raw value",
        "isSummary": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "source": 515.0,
          "value": 515.0,
          "formatted": "515",
          "format": "#,##0",
          "publicationStatus": "Published"
        },
        {
          "source": 264.0,
          "value": 264.0,
          "formatted": "264",
          "format": "#,##0",
          "publicationStatus": "Published"
        },
        {
          "source": 254.0,
          "value": 254.0,
          "formatted": "254",
          "format": "#,##0",
          "publicationStatus": "Published"
        },
        {
          "source": 455.0,
          "value": 455.0,
          "formatted": "455",
          "format": "#,##0",
          "publicationStatus": "Published"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created classes using http://json2csharp.com/ and have tried methods such as:-

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_data);
```

and

```
Value [] vo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Value[]>(json_data);
```

and

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_data);
```

also

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Value [] thisval = jss.Deserialize<Value[]>(json_data);
```

Among others. 
What would be the correct way to extract his information into the classes so then i could work on them. An example of calling the data once deserialized would be helpful.
The main classes I have are

```
public class Value
{
    public double source { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public string formatted { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string publicationStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well `RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_data);` works for me (using blank classes for `Metadata` and `Column`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a working dotNet Fiddle that deserializes the `Values` List. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7P2em6

Wait few seconds when you load the fiddle and notice the output in the Console window. The code should be self-explanatory, but let me know if you need help.

I have also pasted it below for completeness in case dotNetFiddle is not available.

Console Output:

[image: deserialize complex json to c# class]

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the classes from the JSON string.

I think your issue might have been that `Values` is a `List` inside the `Row` object, which, in turn, is a `List` inside the `RootObject`. In other words, `Value`s are stored as a `List` inside a `List`.

Complete Code Listing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    // SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132887/
    // This (my) Answer: 
    // Author: Shiva Manjunath
    // SO Profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/325521/shiva
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {

       string jsonString = @"{
  ""metadata"": {
    ""columnGrouping"": [
      ""area"",
      ""metricType"",
      ""period"",
      ""valueType""
    ],
    ""rowGrouping"": []
  },
  ""columns"": [
    {
      ""area"": {
        ""identifier"": ""E31000040"",
        ""label"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""metricType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""948"",
        ""label"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""period"": {
        ""identifier"": ""fq_Q1_2013_14"",
        ""label"": ""2013/14 Q1"",
        ""altLabel"": ""2013/14 Q1"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""valueType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""raw"",
        ""label"": ""Raw value"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      }
    },
    {
      ""area"": {
        ""identifier"": ""E31000040"",
        ""label"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""metricType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""948"",
        ""label"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""period"": {
        ""identifier"": ""fq_Q2_2013_14"",
        ""label"": ""2013/14 Q2"",
        ""altLabel"": ""2013/14 Q2"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""valueType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""raw"",
        ""label"": ""Raw value"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      }
    },
    {
      ""area"": {
        ""identifier"": ""E31000040"",
        ""label"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""metricType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""948"",
        ""label"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""period"": {
        ""identifier"": ""fq_Q3_2013_14"",
        ""label"": ""2013/14 Q3"",
        ""altLabel"": ""2013/14 Q3"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""valueType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""raw"",
        ""label"": ""Raw value"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      }
    },
    {
      ""area"": {
        ""identifier"": ""E31000040"",
        ""label"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Gtr Manchester Fire"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""metricType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""948"",
        ""label"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""altLabel"": ""Accidental dwelling fires"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""period"": {
        ""identifier"": ""fq_Q4_2013_14"",
        ""label"": ""2013/14 Q4"",
        ""altLabel"": ""2013/14 Q4"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      },
      ""valueType"": {
        ""identifier"": ""raw"",
        ""label"": ""Raw value"",
        ""isSummary"": false
      }
    }
  ],
  ""rows"": [
    {
      ""values"": [
        {
          ""source"": 515.0,
          ""value"": 515.0,
          ""formatted"": ""515"",
          ""format"": ""#,##0"",
          ""publicationStatus"": ""Published""
        },
        {
          ""source"": 264.0,
          ""value"": 264.0,
          ""formatted"": ""264"",
          ""format"": ""#,##0"",
          ""publicationStatus"": ""Published""
        },
        {
          ""source"": 254.0,
          ""value"": 254.0,
          ""formatted"": ""254"",
          ""format"": ""#,##0"",
          ""publicationStatus"": ""Published""
        },
        {
          ""source"": 455.0,
          ""value"": 455.0,
          ""formatted"": ""455"",
          ""format"": ""#,##0"",
          ""publicationStatus"": ""Published""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}";

      Console.WriteLine("Begin JSON Deserialization\n");

      var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
      var rows = rootObject.rows; 
      int rowCounter = 1;
      foreach (Row oneRow in rows)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Row: " + rowCounter);
          int valueCounter = 1;
          foreach(Value oneValue in oneRow.values)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("    Value: " + valueCounter);              
            Console.WriteLine("        source: " + oneValue.source);
            Console.WriteLine("        value: " + oneValue.value);
            Console.WriteLine("        formatted: " + oneValue.formatted);
            Console.WriteLine("        publicationStatus: " + oneValue.publicationStatus);                
            valueCounter++;
          }
          rowCounter++;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("\nEnd JSON Deserialization");

}
}

public class Metadata
{
    public List<string> columnGrouping { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string altLabel { get; set; }
    public bool isSummary { get; set; }
}

public class MetricType
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string altLabel { get; set; }
    public bool isSummary { get; set; }
}

public class Period
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string altLabel { get; set; }
    public bool isSummary { get; set; }
}

public class ValueType
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public bool isSummary { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public Area area { get; set; }
    public MetricType metricType { get; set; }
    public Period period { get; set; }
    public ValueType valueType { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public double source { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public string formatted { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string publicationStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE:** For the `columns` object, you don't need separate classes for the fields (json2csharp.com class generator will default to that). You can store the values in the `columns` object in a dictionary class (if you know that their names will be unique). For an implementation of that (different JSON string, but same json schema type, principle) see this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bFcNM

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer with working example. Just one further question. With the List within a List, how would I reference just one value eg **var test = rootObject.rows[0].values[1].value**

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You would use `rows[0].values[1].value` to access the 1st item in the `rows` list (indexer starts at `0`) and the 2nd `Value` item in the `values` list inside the `rows` list. I have updated the fiddle linked in my answer to print this out too, so check that out!

Answer (score 2):

Use a json to C# generator like [`JSON C# Class Generator`](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/).

You can replace the arrays with Lists and drop the `JsonProperty` attributes if you rename the properties and make them match the json's name.

Here's the output:

```
internal class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("columns")]
    public Column[] Columns { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rows")]
    public Row[] Rows { get; set; }
}

internal class Metadata
{    
    [JsonProperty("columnGrouping")]
    public string[] ColumnGrouping { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowGrouping")]
    public object[] RowGrouping { get; set; }
}

internal class Area
{   
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("altLabel")]
    public string AltLabel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isSummary")]
    public bool IsSummary { get; set; }
}

internal class MetricType
{   
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("altLabel")]
    public string AltLabel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isSummary")]
    public bool IsSummary { get; set; }
}

internal class Period
{   
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("altLabel")]
    public string AltLabel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isSummary")]
    public bool IsSummary { get; set; }
}

internal class ValueType
{   
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isSummary")]
    public bool IsSummary { get; set; }
}

internal class Column
{  
    [JsonProperty("area")]
    public Area Area { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("metricType")]
    public MetricType MetricType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("period")]
    public Period Period { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("valueType")]
    public ValueType ValueType { get; set; }
}

internal class Value
{ 
    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public double Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("formatted")]
    public string Formatted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("format")]
    public string Format { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("publicationStatus")]
    public string PublicationStatus { get; set; }
}

internal class Row
{ 
    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public Value[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I will definitely need this for further programming.