# C# Deserialize Facebook JSON starting with random key

Tags: c#, json, facebook, visual-studio, class

Hello still a newb (student) to C#, I was wondering how to deserialize this kind of JSON data (with JsonConvert and a model class)

JSON example:

```
            {
               "435321729828514": {
                  "id": "435321729828514",
                  "name": "Kursaal Oostende"
               },
               "56302776046": {
                  "id": "56302776046",
                  "name": "Caf\u00e9 Charlatan"
               }
            }
```

Repository class:

```
        public class FB
        {
            public async static Task<FBModel> Entries(string ids)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?ids="+ ids +"&fields=id,name&access_token=secret_token");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        FBModel entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FBModel>(s);
                        return entries;
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
        public class FBModel
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return ID + ": " + Name;
            }
        }
```

MainPage.xaml (call):

```
        private static FBModel _entries; // global variable
        // ...
        _entries = await FB.Entries(ids_to_pass);
```

**--------- Solved (model) ----------**

```
            public class FBModel
            {
                #region properties
                public string Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public Events Events { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }
            public class Events
            {
                #region props
                public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
                public Paging Paging { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }

            public class Datum
            {
                #region props
                public string Description { get; set; }
                public string End_time { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public Place Place { get; set; }
                public string Start_time { get; set; }
                public string Id { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }

            public class Place
            {
                #region props
                public string Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public Location Location { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }

            public class Location
            {
                #region props
                public string City { get; set; }
                public string Country { get; set; }
                public double Latitude { get; set; }
                public double Longitude { get; set; }
                public string Street { get; set; }
                public string Zip { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }

            #region not important
            public class Paging
            {
                #region props
                public Cursors Cursors { get; set; }
                public string Next { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }

            public class Cursors
            {
                #region props
                public string Before { get; set; }
                public string After { get; set; }
                #endregion
            }
```

**-------- Solved (complete JSON) ----------**

```
        {
           "435321729828514": {
              "id": "435321729828514",
              "name": "Kursaal Oostende",
              "events": {
                 "data": [
                    {
                       "description": "CHRISTOFF, ...",
                       "end_time": "2017-11-25T23:00:00+0100",
                       "name": "Vrienden Voor Het Leven",
                       "place": {
                          "name": "Kursaal Oostende",
                          "location": {
                             "city": "Oostende",
                             "country": "Belgium",
                             "latitude": 51.2312299,
                             "longitude": 2.9126599,
                             "street": "Westhelling 12",
                             "zip": "8400"
                          },
                          "id": "435321729828514"
                       },
                       "start_time": "2017-11-25T20:00:00+0100",
                       "id": "161310354323914"
                    }
                 ],
                 "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                       "before": "MTYxMzEwMzU0MzIzOTE0",
                       "after": "MTYxMzEwMzU0MzIzOTE0"
                    },
                    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/435321729828514/events?access_token=EAAH2ZAZAq846IBAM9ZAX0LWpDxlzFaPr8jNOxDct2tZBw7YJAtnYxIlVud67hiXI51ybmhLcz4AhMtiVxZBBcPixx9wB9ntF1ZBRhSIuSxeUu83mg6tZBc0BseLpdmkWuu7bohQxXvvLUe67pjETnqDOj8PzFZAXHHAyqEqYrWOXvAZDZD\u002522&pretty=1&limit=1&after=MTYxMzEwMzU0MzIzOTE0"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

**-------- Solved (Repository) ---------**

```
            public async static Task<List<FBModel>> Entries(string ids)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?ids="+ ids +"&fields=id,name,events.limit(60)&access_token=secret_token");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, FBModel>>(s);
                        List<FBModel> data = entries.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
                        return data;
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: _entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FBModel>(jsonString);

Comment: you have already deserialized in repository class. And in MainPage.Xaml you are getting object.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't parse it into a usable object. I don't know how to fill my properties in the FBModel class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you have to do.

**Step 1: Convert your json to Dictionary.**

```
 var dataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, FBModel>>(yourJsonstring);
```

**Step 2: Then get list of object**

```
        List<FBModel> data=new List<FBModel>();
        foreach (var item in dataDictionary)
        {
           data.Add(item.Value);
        }
```

Step 2 can be done as a linq query

```
List<FBModel> data= dataDictionary.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

**Update**
your class structure should be like below to access the event data.

```
public class FBModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Events Events { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID + ": " + Name;
    }
}

public class Events
{
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}



 public class Data
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string End_Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
    public string Start_Time { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have to create your class structure. Can you put a complete sample JSON in your question I will update my answer according to your sample. Check this sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132887/convert-complex-json-to-c-sharp-class

Comment: You are about to save my semester :) Thanks again. I wonder what happens if there are no "Events" or when there is no data for the property. Is that Try Catch material or rather validation in Getter or Setter ?

Comment: that property will be null. you have to do null check before you use it

Comment: How could I access all fields ? By inheritance? I cannot access the Events property ect. now :/

Comment: It's okay I figured the model out already ... I tried to display it by using the MainPage.xaml which was too hard for me to do. I'm just going to bind it all, different approach. Thank you for all the time and help :)